# Find error code from return streamreader

Tags: c#, php

What I need is the error code returned from a string, I can do it in `php` but it needs to be converted to C# and any one convert this code  to C#

string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nma>
    <error code="402" resettimer="TIMELEFT"></error>
</nma>

preg_match("/<error code=\"(.*?)\".*>(.*?)<\/error>/i", $return, $out);


// return $out[1] = 200;
```

I have tried this with no success

```
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(response, "<error code=\"(.*?)\".*>(.*?)</error>")){
         Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", 
                           m.Value, m.Index);
```

Comment: Why not use a xml parser? Regex is not for parsing xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [`Match.Groups`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
string response = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
                    <nma>
                        <error code=""402"" resettimer=""TIMELEFT"">test</error>
                    </nma>";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(response, "<error code=\"(.*?)\".*>(.*?)</error>"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]); // 402
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2]); // test
}
```